# Playing audio from live streaming URL

Tags: asp.net, http-live-streaming, audio-player, icecast

I'm using IceCast server with RadioBOSS to broadcast audio for a radio station. I've got the live stream link working fine in my browser, but when I add it in an Asp.Net web app it doesn't work (you can see the output log). When I replace the link with one such as this: https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/262.mp3, where it has ".mp3" at the end it works just fine. I had similar issues in Xamarin.Forms and the solution was using the Exo player.
[image: Asp.Net Code]
[image: Output Log]

Comment: I'm confused as to the role of ASP.net in this. As long as that HTML snippet gets served to the browser? Or do you mean by "web app" that you are using a runtime to render HTML in a desktop application?

Comment: @TBR I'm using an ASP.Net project because I have other uses besides playing audio. you can say it's a website for managing radio station programs and timetable

Comment: So you are serving this to a browser? Which Browser are you opening this with? That's important to know as engines behave differently.

Comment: One of the reasons it may not work is because your stream is using HTTP protocol (not https) and ASP web stuff does not respect http streams. This is also why CDN link that you provided is working, not because it has .mp3 extension.

Answer (score 1):

The `.mp3` extension is meaningless.  The `Content-Type` response header is what dictates type.

In your example, you've specified `audio/mp3`... this is incorrect.  Use `audio/mpeg` instead.  Additionally, while you can play audio in a video element, I assume you want to change that to `<audio>`.

If this isn't playing for you, show the network log of what's happening.  The log you show tells us nothing of importance.